# Splitting string based on word

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string composed by words divided by'#'. For instance 'this#is#an#example' and I need to extract the last word or the last two words according to the second to last word.

If the second to last is 'myword' I need the last two words otherwise just the last one.

```
'this#is#an#example' => 'example'
'this#is#an#example#using#myword#also' => 'myword#also'
```

Is there a better way than splitting and checking the second to last? perhaps using regular expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the end-of-line anchor `$` and make the `myword#` prefix optional:

```
str = 'this#is#an#example'
str[/(?:#)((myword#)?[^#]+)$/, 1]
#=> "example"

str = 'this#is#an#example#using#myword#also'
str[/(?:#)((myword#)?[^#]+)$/, 1]
#=> "myword#also"
```

However, I don't think using a regular expression is "better" in this case. I would use something like Santosh's (deleted) answer: split the line by `#` and use an if clause.

```
def foo(str)
  *, a, b = str.split('#')
  if a == 'myword'
    "#{a}##{b}"
  else
    b
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'this#is#an#example#using#myword#also'
array = str.split('#')
array[-2] == 'myword' ? array[-2..-1].join('#') : array[-1]

With regex:

'this#is#an#example'[/(myword\#)*\w+$/]
# => "example"

'this#is#an#example#using#myword#also'[/(myword\#)*\w+$/]
# => "myword#also"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, your snippet does not answer to my question "Is there a better way than splitting and checking the second to last?"